# Why spring boot devtools called main method twice?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-devtools

I'm using spring boot devtools with my project. When i write

```
System.out.println("test");
```

before main, it printing twice in console.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("test");
    SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
}
```

When i remove

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

in pom.xml file,it printing once

Comment: Thanks! Due to this question, I was able to locate my problem and I will add the information here in case it's helpful to someone else:  If the spring-boot-devtools are enabled, all code executed after `SpringApplication.run` (which means all code executed on the second run) will not call methods that were added by an `asm.MethodVisitor` to the bytecode. Even though the bytecode is exactly the same, these method calls never get through with the devtools installed. I still have no idea why, but removing the devtools fixes it.

Answer (score 7):

Not only twice, if the spring context need to be refreshed, it will run once more.

I believe it is a designed behavior.

The devtools auto-refresh the context instead of restarting manually.

Comment: This was doing our QA environment very crazy.